# Eslint in angular placing = in incorrect place

Tags: angular, eslint

I am setting up eslint in an agular project.  In my html files, it will see something like this:

`

```
*ngIf="
  config.inputType == 'string' ||
  config.inputType == 'url' ||
  config.inputType == 'number' ||
  config.inputType == 'text'
"
```

`

It it yells at me with a red line under the == since it breaks the @angular-eslint/recommended/eqeqeq rule.

And change it to this (this change happens if I do it in my IDE or by running the ng lint --fix command).

`

```
          *ngIf="
            config.inputType == 'string' ||
=            config.inputType == 'url' ||
            config.inputType == 'number' ||
            config.inputType == 'text'
          "
```

`

You can see that it has put the additional = at the beginning of the next line and not where it is needed.

This seems to only be happening when or (||) or and (&&) is involved.

Here is what my .eslintrc.json file looks like:

`

```
{
  "root": true,
  "ignorePatterns": ["projects/**/*", "**/node_modules", "**/.angular/**"],
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["*.ts"],
      "parserOptions": {
        "project": ["tsconfig.json", "e2e/tsconfig.json"],
        "createDefaultProgram": true
      },
      "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/recommended",
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/recommended--extra",
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/process-inline-templates"
      ],
      "rules": {
        "@angular-eslint/component-selector": [
          "error",
          {
            "prefix": "app",
            "style": "kebab-case",
            "type": "element"
          }
        ],
        "@angular-eslint/no-output-native": [
          "off",
          {
            "prefix": "app",
            "style": "kebab-case",
            "type": "element"
          }
        ],
        "@angular-eslint/directive-selector": [
          "error",
          {
            "prefix": "app",
            "style": "camelCase",
            "type": "attribute"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "files": ["*.html"],
      "extends": ["plugin:@angular-eslint/template/recommended"],
      "rules": {}
    },
    {
      "files": ["*.html"],
      "excludedFiles": ["*inline-template-*.component.html"],
      "extends": ["plugin:prettier/recommended"],
      "rules": {
        "prettier/prettier": ["error", { "parser": "angular" }]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

`

I have tried changing around my .eslintrc.json file with no affect.

Comment: Probably the autofix is broken, but I suppose that you can fix the problem yourself by replacing `==` with `===`. Since the second argument is a string this operation is safe

Comment: Yep, the autofix is broken: https://github.com/angular-eslint/angular-eslint/issues/538